# Cross-Origin Request Blocked Angular JS Put request

Tags: javascript, angularjs, yii

I'm developing a REST-ful application using Yii framework for the server side and Angular JS for the client side

I'm using the restfulyii extension to generate the api

:And I'm facing a problem when I'm sending a PUT request.

```
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at ..... This can be fixed by moving the resource to the same domain or enabling CORS.
```

**But it's working for post + get requests**

I saw different solutions but none of them worked.

I tried to put those is server side

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: x-requested-with, Content-Type, origin, authorization, accept, client-security-token");
header("Access-Control-Max-Age: 1000");
```

and tried to put this code in the angular js module:

```
$httpProvider.defaults.useXDomain = true;
delete $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'];
```

and also I tried to put

```
 $http.defaults.headers.post["Content-Type"] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
```

The request converted into OPTIONS request
and the response from the server became as following:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Headers:x-requested-with, Content-Type, origin, authorization, accept, client-security-token 
Access-Control-Allow-Methods:GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS Access-Control-Allow-
Origin:http://localhost:8383
 Access-Control-Max-Age:1000
 Connection:close
 Content-Type:text/html Date:Fri, 24 Oct 2014 06:49:32 GMT
 Server:Apache/2.4.7 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.1e PHP/5.5.9 X-Powered-By:PHP/5.5.9
```

Comment: try to put exact domain name instead of * into header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");

Comment: But when I send the exact request using postman extension, it works!

Comment: How are you loading your angular site? Are you using the file:// or http:// protocol?

Answer (score 0):

I have a base controller for all my rest controllers that use restangular which has the following events.

```
public function restEvents()
{
    $this->onRest('req.cors.access.control.allow.origin', function() {
        return ['*']; //List of sites allowed to make CORS requests 
    });

    $this->onRest('req.cors.access.control.allow.methods', function() {
        return ['GET', 'POST', 'PUT', 'DELETE', 'OPTIONS']; //List of allowed http methods (verbs) 
    });

    $this->onRest('req.auth.cors', function ($allowed_origins) {
        if (in_array('*', $allowed_origins)) {
            return true;
        }
        if((isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN'])) && (( array_search($_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN'], $allowed_origins)) !== false )) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;   
    });

    $this->onRest('req.cors.access.control.allow.headers', function($application_id) {
        return ["X_{$application_id}_CORS", "Content-Type", "Authorization", "X_REST_REQUEST"];
    });
```

}

Client side I am using restangular with  the following options:

`RestangularProvider.setDefaultHttpFields({withCredentials: true});
  RestangularProvider.setDefaultHeaders({X_REST_CORS: 'Yes'});
  RestangularProvider.setDefaultHttpFields({cache: false});`

I hope this helps....